# How to make the value of the calculator button appear on the display upon clicking it?

Tags: javascript, calculator

This is my first post here so I apologize in advance if I mess up with the formatting of my message.

I am doing the CareerFoundry web development course and we are asked to code a calculator using javascript and jQuery. I am totally new to coding and it is all very confusing to me. So far I have managed to create and style my calculator using HTML, CSS and Javascript and now I need to make it functional. I am on the step where I want to click on any calculator button and have its value appear in the display div. I have no idea how to go about it... I am trying to use the append method, but it doesn't work the way I code it... Also, could you give me any hints as to how to continue after solving this step? Thanks!

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="calculator">
      <div id="display"></div>
      <div class="row" id="interface"></div>
      <div class="button" id="CE"><p>CE</p></div>
    </div><!-- end calculator -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/interfaceItems.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*CSS*

```
body {
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Arial, Lucida, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}

#calculator {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 320px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #404040;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 20px;
}

#display {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: right;
  height: 73px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 2.5px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 10px 2.5px 10px;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 73px;
  height: 73px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

#CE {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 73px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: skyblue;

}

.button:hover,
#CE:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.button:active,
#CE:active {
  transform: scale(0.98,0.98);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px;
}
```

*JS*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < interfaceItems.length; ++i) {
    $('#interface').append('\
      <div class="button">\
        <p>' + interfaceItems[i].text + '</p>\
      </div>\
    ');
    $('#interface .button', this).on('click', function() {
      $('#display').append('<p>' + interfaceItems[i].value + '</p>');
    });
  };
});

var interfaceItems = [
    {
        text: '7',
        value: 7
    },
    {
        text: '8',
        value: 8
    },
    {
        text: '9',
        value: 9
    },
    {
        text: '÷',
        value: '/'
    },
    {
        text: '4',
        value: 4
    },
    {
        text: '5',
        value: 5
    },
    {
        text: '6',
        value: 6
    },
    {
        text: '×',
        value: '*'
    },
    {
        text: '1',
        value: 1
    },
    {
        text: '2',
        value: 2
    },
    {
        text: '3',
        value: 3
    },
    {
        text: '−',
        value: '-'
    },
    {
        text: '0',
        value: 0
    },
    {
        text: '.',
        value: '.'
    },
    {
        text: '=',
        value: '='
    },
    {
        text: '+',
        value: '+'
    },
];
```

Comment: What's in `interfaceItems.js`?

Comment: Open up the console. You'll see you get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`. That should get you started on the right path.. you can google the error if you don't know what it means

Comment: These are the types of things I wish folks would include a codepen or stackblitz or something with since I'm generally too lazy to go load their stuff up too troubleshoot. :)

Comment: Inside the interfaceItems.js is the array I posted towards the end of the code.

Comment: I have the console opened all the time and saw that error. No idea what to do about it though... When I used the text property above there was no error so I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thank you for pointing this out though! :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes because of a scoping issue/variable issue.

You get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` at this line in your code:

```
$('#display').append('<p>' + interfaceItems[i].value + '</p>');
```

If you add a console log to get the value of `i` right before this line- you see the value of `i` is 16. Why? Because on the document ready function you have a for loop

`for(var i = 0; i < interfaceItems.length; ++i) {`

By the end of this loop you set the value of i to `16`. You are getting undefined because javascript uses 0 indexes so even though you have 16 elements in your interfaceItems array- the 16th index is undefined (it only goes from 0-15).

To fix this- I think you want to get rid of using i in your onclick function. You can use something like

`this.innerText.trim()` to get the text of the item and then use that to make it appear inside the calculator.

You will have to create a new SO question to help with other parts of your calculator app. I hope this solves your issue of why your onclick function wasn't working. Using the console and adding `console.log` statements to debug javascript code is very useful and will save trips from coming here in the future. Best of luck with completing the calculator app!

Comment: Thank you so much! I would never have thought of this. I will try to implement your solution! Hopefully with success! :)